# The buttons will not show up in the IOS simulator, can anyone assist? (Code Provided Below)

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

**The code below shows a potential login screen and everything works except for the buttons. I am trying to figure out why that is......**

I thought maybe it was the version of Xcode i was using(Xcode 13), but the still doesn't seem like the reason or i would have received an error message.

```
import UIKit


class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    
    struct Constants {
        static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 8.0
    }
//Declaration of login fields
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTaploginButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        createAccountButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapcreateAccountButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        termsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTaptermsButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        privacyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapprivacyButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        usernameEmailField.delegate = self
        passwordField.delegate = self
        
        addSubviews()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    
    private let usernameEmailField: UITextField = {
         let field = UITextField()
         field.placeholder = "Username or Email"
         field.returnKeyType = .next
         field.leftViewMode = .always
         field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
         field.autocapitalizationType = .none
         field.autocorrectionType = .no
         field.layer.masksToBounds = true
         field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
         field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
         
         return field
     }()

    private let passwordField: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Password"
        field.returnKeyType = .next
        field.leftViewMode = .always
        field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        field.autocapitalizationType = .none
        field.autocorrectionType = .no
        field.layer.masksToBounds = true
        field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        return field
    }()
    
    private let loginButton: UIButton = {
        let loginbutton = UIButton()
        loginbutton.setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
        loginbutton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        loginbutton.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        loginbutton.backgroundColor = .link
        loginbutton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        return UIButton()
    }()
    
    private let termsButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Terms of Service", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.secondaryLabel, for: .normal)
        return UIButton()
    }()
    
    private let privacyButton: UIButton = {
        return UIButton()
    }()
    
    private let createAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("New User? Create an Account", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        button.setTitleColor(.label, for: .normal)
        return UIButton()
    }()
    //Picture behind the Logo
    private let headerView: UIView = {
        let header = UIView()
        header.clipsToBounds = true
        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Bluewater"))
        header.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        return header
    }()
 
 
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        //assigning frames
        
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: 0.0,
                                  width: view.width,
                                  height: view.height/3.0
        )
        
        usernameEmailField.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                          y: headerView.bottom + 10,
                                  width: view.width-50,
                                  height: 52.0
        )
        
        passwordField.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                     y: usernameEmailField.bottom + 10,
                                  width: view.width-50,
                                  height: 52.0
        )
        
        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                   y: passwordField.bottom + 10,
                                  width: view.width-50,
                                  height: 52.0
        )
        
        createAccountButton.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                               y: loginButton.bottom + 10,
                                               width: view.width-50,
                                               height: 52.0
        )
        termsButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: view.height-view.safeAreaInsets.bottom-100, width: view.width-20, height: 50)
        
        configurationView()
    }
 
    
    private func configurationView() {
        guard headerView.subviews.count == 1 else {
            return
        }
        guard let backgroundView = headerView.subviews.first else {
            return
        }
        backgroundView.frame = headerView.bounds
        
        //Pic Pool Logo
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ClearLogo"))
        headerView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: headerView.width/4.0,
 
                                 y: view.safeAreaInsets.top,
                                 width: headerView.width/2.0,
                                 height: headerView.height - view.safeAreaInsets.top)
    }

    
    private func addSubviews(){
       
        view.addSubview(usernameEmailField)
        view.addSubview(passwordField)
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        view.addSubview(termsButton)
        view.addSubview(privacyButton)
        view.addSubview(createAccountButton)
        view.addSubview(headerView)
    }

    
    @objc private func didTaploginButton() {}
    
    @objc private func didTaptermsButton() {}
    
    @objc private func didTapprivacyButton() {}
    
 
    @objc private func didTapcreateAccountButton() {}
 


    
    

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        
        
    }
```

Comment: ‍♂️ `return UIButton()` <- Look at your properties for your buttons, each is doing this, so NO text is been displayed (and the face palm is for me, because I've spent the last 15 minutes scratching my head)

Answer (score 1):

Take a real hard look at...

```
private let loginButton: UIButton = {
    let loginbutton = UIButton()
    loginbutton.setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
    loginbutton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    loginbutton.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
    loginbutton.backgroundColor = .link
    loginbutton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    return UIButton()
}()
```

see anything wrong?  Maybe focus in on `return UIButton()`

So, changing it to...

```
private let loginButton: UIButton = {
    let loginbutton = UIButton()
    loginbutton.setTitle("Log In", for: [])
    loginbutton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    loginbutton.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
    loginbutton.backgroundColor = .link
    loginbutton.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
    return loginbutton
}()
```

will produce...

[image]

## Runnable example

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  StackOverflow
//
//  Created by Shane Whitehead on 4/5/2022.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    struct Constants {
        static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 8.0
    }
    //Declaration of login fields
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTaploginButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        createAccountButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapcreateAccountButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        termsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTaptermsButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        privacyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapprivacyButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        usernameEmailField.delegate = self
        passwordField.delegate = self
        
        addSubviews()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    private let usernameEmailField: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Username or Email"
        field.returnKeyType = .next
        field.leftViewMode = .always
        field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        field.autocapitalizationType = .none
        field.autocorrectionType = .no
        field.layer.masksToBounds = true
        field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        
        return field
    }()
    
    private let passwordField: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Password"
        field.returnKeyType = .next
        field.leftViewMode = .always
        field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        field.autocapitalizationType = .none
        field.autocorrectionType = .no
        field.layer.masksToBounds = true
        field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        return field
    }()
    
    private let loginButton: UIButton = {
        let loginbutton = UIButton()
        loginbutton.setTitle("Log In", for: [])
        loginbutton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        loginbutton.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        loginbutton.backgroundColor = .link
        loginbutton.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
        return loginbutton
    }()
    
    private let termsButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Terms of Service", for: [])
        button.setTitleColor(.secondaryLabel, for: [])
        return button
    }()
    
    private let privacyButton: UIButton = {
        return UIButton()
    }()
    
    private let createAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: [])
        button.setTitle("New User? Create an Account", for: [])
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        button.setTitleColor(.label, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    //Picture behind the Logo
    private let headerView: UIView = {
        let header = UIView()
        header.clipsToBounds = true
        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Bluewater"))
        header.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        return header
    }()
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        //assigning frames
        
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: 0.0,
                                  width: view.width,
                                  height: view.height/3.0
        )
        
        usernameEmailField.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                          y: headerView.bottom + 10,
                                          width: view.width-50,
                                          height: 52.0
        )
        
        passwordField.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                     y: usernameEmailField.bottom + 10,
                                     width: view.width-50,
                                     height: 52.0
        )

        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                   y: passwordField.bottom + 10,
                                   width: view.width-50,
                                   height: 52.0
        )
        
        createAccountButton.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                           y: loginButton.bottom + 10,
                                           width: view.width-50,
                                           height: 52.0
        )
        termsButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: view.height-view.safeAreaInsets.bottom-100, width: view.width-20, height: 50)
        
        configurationView()
    }
    
    
    private func configurationView() {
        guard headerView.subviews.count == 1 else {
            return
        }
        guard let backgroundView = headerView.subviews.first else {
            return
        }
        backgroundView.frame = headerView.bounds
        
        //Pic Pool Logo
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ClearLogo"))
        headerView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: headerView.width/4.0,
                                 
                                 y: view.safeAreaInsets.top,
                                 width: headerView.width/2.0,
                                 height: headerView.height - view.safeAreaInsets.top)
    }
    
    
    private func addSubviews(){
        view.addSubview(usernameEmailField)
        view.addSubview(passwordField)
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        view.addSubview(termsButton)
        view.addSubview(privacyButton)
        view.addSubview(createAccountButton)
        view.addSubview(headerView)
    }
    
    @objc private func didTaploginButton() {}
    @objc private func didTaptermsButton() {}
    @objc private func didTapprivacyButton() {}
    @objc private func didTapcreateAccountButton() {}
}

extension UIView {
    var width: CGFloat {
        return bounds.width
    }
    
    var height: CGFloat {
        return bounds.height
    }
    
    var bottom: CGFloat {
        return frame.minY + bounds.height
    }
}
```

I'd also, strongly, recommend either making the time to learn how to use auto layout OR SwiftUI instead

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out! I wanted to learn the UIkit because it's still heavily used, but I've started understanding why SwiftUI is the preferred choice by far!